# Python/Tkinter Button and Entry on the same window

Tags: python, button, python-2.7, tkinter

I'm a beginner in Python (2.7.5). So here is a basic question

I'm trying to create a window with both a Button and some Entry but for some reason it doesn't work.
If I try to make a window with only entries or only a button it works but not with both the button and the entry at the same time.

so the question is basically: **How to create a window with both a button and an entry ?**

Below is some script:

```
from Tkinter import*

def super_function():
    fen1.quit

fen1 = Tk()
entr = []
for i in range(10):
    entr.append(Entry(fen1))
    entr[i].grid(row=i)
Button(fen1,text='store everything in a list',command=fen1.quit).pack(side=BOTTOM)
fen1.mainloop()
```

Thank you !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are using `pack` and `grid` at the same time.  Instead, you should use only one:

```
from Tkinter import *

def super_function():
    fen1.quit

fen1 = Tk()
entr = []
for i in xrange(10):
    entr.append(Entry(fen1))
    entr[i].grid(row=i)
# Use grid instead of pack here
Button(fen1,text='store everything in a list',command=super_function).grid()
fen1.mainloop()
```

Comment: @Remi.b: Don't mention it!  Also, in case you didn't notice, I used `xrange` instead of `range` for your loop.  `range` generates an unnecessary list where as `xrange` returns an `xrange` iterator.  The difference is your code will be cleaner and faster.  Just in case you were wondering.