# How does Pythons .grid() function work

Tags: python, tkinter, grid-layout

I try to use the following to align buttons but it doesn't work

```
#creates entry inputs for answers
entry=Entry(master)
entry.pack()
entry.focus_set() 

#button 1 created and used to call addition function
b1 = Button(master, text="+", command=callback)
b1.pack(side=LEFT)

#button 2 created and used to call subtraction function
b2 = Button(master, text="-", command=callback2)
b2.pack(side=LEFT)

#button 3 created and used to call divison function
b3 = Button(master, text="/", command=callback3)
b3.pack(side=LEFT)

#button 4 created and used to call multiplication function
b4 = Button(master, text="*", command=callback4)
b4.pack(side=LEFT)

#button 5 created and used to check answers
b5 = Button(master, text="Check Ans", width=10, command=callbackinput)
b5.pack(side=LEFT)
```

*edit* I am trying to get an entry to sit center above four buttons aligned left

what I've got so far([image](http://i.imgur.com/S9QaP50.png)) need to align entry above buttons

also when .grid(row= , column=) is used the GUI doesn't appear

Comment: As far as I can tell from "does not work": Use `grid` _or_ `pack`, not both.

Comment: sorry man I'm not very good thanks :D

Comment: I assume you're using some sort of widget library (e.g. Tk, wxWidgets)? If so, you might want to tag the question appropriately (and maybe update the title too), for your question to get attention from the right people...

Comment: Not enough code is shown here to make a determination - your button code is clearly wrong but there's no telling how you've set up the Entry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're using `pack` as your geometry manager, tkinter doesn't know what to do when you call `grid` on one of the buttons. Pick one geometry manager and stick with it throughout your window.

```
from tkinter import *

master = Tk()

# some dummy callback functions
callback, callback2, callback3, callback4, callbackinput = [lambda: None]*5    

#creates entry inputs for answers
entry=Entry(master)
entry.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=6)
entry.focus_set() 

#button 1 created and used to call addition function
b1 = Button(master, text="+", command=callback)
b1.grid(row=1, column=0)

#button 2 created and used to call subtraction function
b2 = Button(master, text="-", command=callback2)
b2.grid(row=1, column=1)

#button 3 created and used to call divison function
b3 = Button(master, text="/", command=callback3)
b3.grid(row=1, column=2)

#button 4 created and used to call multiplication function
b4 = Button(master, text="*", command=callback4)
b4.grid(row=1, column=3)

#button 5 created and used to check answers
b5 = Button(master, text="Check Ans", width=10, command=callbackinput)
b5.grid(row=1, column=4, columnspan=2)
```

Creates a window that looks like:

[image: Tk window]

Comment: Thanks Adam this worked, so stick to one geometry manager got it.

Comment: @jmckee one ***per window***. If you needed to create a new `TopLevel` with just one `Label` in it, for example, you should feel free to `pack` that in.

Comment: why does pythons entry break the GUI

Comment: @jmckee how so? It's a predetermined width, which is less wide than that of the whole screen. You can fix that with `sticky`. Do `entry.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=6, sticky=EW)`

Comment: see I need to press say the + button then be able to use the entry box as well. As of now I have to use input outside the GUI

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17819332/python-tkinter-button-and-entry-on-the-same-window this was the problem need to change all .pack() to .grid()

Answer (score 1):

The problem in your code is that you're calling both `grid` and `pack`. Tkinter has three geometry managers: those two, plus `place`. A widget can only be controlled by one of those at a time. When you call more than one, it is only the last one that has any effect. Thus, any effect the call to `grid` has is nullified when you call `pack`.